# Having launcher activity in a library in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-launcher

I want to have a `launcher` `activity` inside a library which my app includes. I define that `activity` like this:

```
<activity
   android:name="com.something.MyActivity"
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_app"
   android:label="@string/second_app_name"
   android:taskAffinity="com.something"
   android:theme="@style/MyTheme">

   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

But it doesn't appear as a `launcher` `activity`. It appears as a separate launcher icon, but not when it's in a library.

What should I do? Am I doing anything wrong or is it impossible to do so?

Comment: Is this an Android Studio library module? Does the hosting application also have an `<activity>` element for this activity? When you viewed your merged manifest (e.g., `build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`), does your `<activity>` element appear?

Comment: @CommonsWare It's a project, not a module, and yes, activity element is in `build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`. I found out that it seems to be a problem related to my launcher (which is the default android launcher). When I uninstall the app and install library-included version, second launcher icon appears. But not on update.

Comment: "It's a project, not a module" -- most Android Studio projects are made of 1+ modules. For example, in a project created by the new-project wizard, `app/` is a module. "I found out that it seems to be a problem related to my launcher (which is the default android launcher)" -- there is no single "default android launcher". There is a default for your device or emulator, but there are hundreds of different default launchers across the thousands of Android device models. That being said, a buggy launcher certainly could have the behavior that you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that problem is related to device's launcher. When I uninstall the app (with one launcher activity) and install this, I see two launcher icons and everything's fine.